# Does having different capacity RAM sticks reduce performance compared to 2 sticks of the same size?

Tags: windows, memory, motherboard, performance, dual-channel

I have an **Acer A515-51G-58GJ** notebook that comes with 4 gigs of RAM that's soldered on the motherboard (HWiNFO says it's a **SK Hynix DDR4-2400 stick - HMA851S6AFR6N-UH**).

I upgraded the RAM on this notebook to a total of 8 gigs by adding a Crucial 4GB DDR4-2400 stick (model **CT4G4SFS824A**)

I haven't run into any problems with this configuration but I noticed that with my usage, almost 6-7 gigs of RAM is always in use, so I want to increase the capacity to 12 GB.

Since my notebook only has 1 RAM slot, I intend to remove the existing 4GB stick and replace it with a Crucial 8GB stick (model **CT8G4SFS824A**)

I read online that the best way to go is to have RAM in dual-channel mode with both sticks having identical capacities, make and model to reduce any performance bottlenecks.

I want to know if memory performance will be affected/degraded and if so, by how much if I replace the 4GB stick with an 8GB stick that is exactly the same in all aspects apart from size.

Here's what my config currently looks like:

[image: Image 1][image: Image 1]

Comment: I have no SPD info on the soldered RAM but HWiNFO was able to get me [this from the DMI table](https://i.imgur.com/IWx8ySA.png)

Answer (score 1):

The
[Aspire 5 series Product Sheet](https://plasico.bg/resources/aspire-5.pdf)
says:

> Memory : Dual-channel DDR4 SDRAM support
>
> - 4 GB of onboard DDR4 system memory
> - Up to 20 GB of DDR4 system memory.

So it seems like the motherboard was built to use more than 12 GB of RAM.

I verified using the [Crucial](https://www.crucial.com/) site to suggest
RAM upgrades, and the result were upgrades to 4GB, 8G and 16GB sticks.

The specification for the 8GB stick was:

> DDR4 PC4-19200 • CL=17 • DUAL RANKED • X8 BASED • UNBUFFERED • NON-ECC • DDR4-2400 • 1.2V • 1024MEG X 64

You don't have to buy Crucial, but best to buy RAM which has very similar
characteristics.

Comment: That would work for laptop but they were asking if there would be any performance change with different size sticks.

Comment: Yes, I know the 8GB stick would work but I wanted to know if there'd be a performance hit. I did a little more digging and it seems it's possible that mismatched RAM can run in dual channel mode on Intel boards with something called 'Flex mode' where a total capacity equal to double the capacity of the smaller RAM would run in dual channel mode while the remaining capacity of the larger RAM would run in single channel mode. I'm not sure if I got that right though.

Comment: @HazardousGlitch: There shouldn't be a performance hit, since this laptop was built by design to support different-sized sticks. The specification of the stick are important, which is why I went to Crucial who are usually correct.

Comment: @harrymc I trust Crucial so I'll go with their memory modules but with mismatched RAMs, since this is an Intel chipset they'd be running in Flex mode right? I want to know if there's a difference in performance when running in Flex mode vs dual channel mode.

Comment: Dual Channel is a property of the memory controller, which your model can do by all reports. In any case, Dual Channel is not guaranteed to be faster, since it requires two cores to use memory in parallel, but from different RAM modules. This happening would be rare, and with a configuration of 4GB+8GB the chances would be against it, as Windows doesn't optimize RAM allocation for it. My advice: Forget Dual Channel and get your RAM, the difference would be unnoticeable with or without Flex mode.

Comment: *"Dual Channel is not guaranteed to be faster, since it requires two cores to use memory in parallel"* -- Wrong.

Comment: @sawdust: Not wrong but [right](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-channel_memory_architecture#Performance).